# What can be measured on a curve?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, functional-equations, cubics

I am doing a maths problem in which I must mathematically compare models when the assumption that polynomial was the ideal fit is changed. I then used a cosine function to fit it. What can be measured on a curve to compare and contrast them? I've had it suggested to find the second derivative but what will this show me? Will it compare how tight the curves are?

Answer (score 0):

Take the integral of the square of the difference between the actual curve and your model, across an appropriate interval: $$\int_a^b \left(f(x)-m(x) \right)^2 dx$$

This is the limit of "accumulated errors" of your model $m(x)$ compared to the actual function $f(x)$, weighted by a squares approach, across the interval you are interested in.

A model with close fit in most of the interval but large deviance in some of it will be weighted unfavourably compared to a model with consistent "okay" deviance. If you really want to hammer down a large deviance, you can use higher powers, but this will require a modulus correction, i.e. the absolute value of the difference (a problem which is negated when using even integer exponents).

A similar approach is used in the least squares linear approximation method, where the discrete equivalent of the above expression is minimised, and the resulting curve used as the model.